# javascript not firing onmessage / onopen methods for websocket connection

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

I am trying to implement a basic server client communication through web sockets. I have console prints in my server to tell me when a conection opeened and when a message is recieved. As soon as i press send button on my client, i get an "something recieved" console print from the server but the onopen function of client (pasted below) is not fired. Same happens with other functions as well. What am i doing wrong ?

Here is my code :

Client Side code for html age:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("msg").value = "Website Opened";
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/PushServlet/echo");

    ws.onopen = function () 
    {
    document.getElementById("msgArea").textContent += "Connection Opened \n";
    };

    function connect()
    {
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/PushServlet/echo");
    var wss = "ws = " + ws.toString();
    document.getElementById("msgArea").textContent += wss;
    };

    ws.onmessage = function(message) 
    {
        document.getElementById("msgArea").textContent += message.data;              
    };

   function postToServer() 
    {
        if(ws == null)
    {
        document.getElementById("msgArea").textContent += "Connection Null \n";
    }
        ws.send(document.getElementById("msg").value);
        document.getElementById("msg").value = "";
    };

   ws.onclose = function(evt) 
   {
    document.getElementById("msgArea").textContent += "closed";
   };

   function updateTextBox() 
    {
        document.getElementById("msg").value = "Blah Blah Blah";
    };

    function closeConnect() 
    {
    document.getElementById("msg").value = "Blah Blah Blah";
        ws.close();
    };
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="100" id="msgArea" readonly></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="msg" type="text" value="Website Opened 1" />
        <button type="submit" id="sendButton" onclick="postToServer()">Send</button>
        <button type="submit" id="update_button" onclick="connect()" > Update </button>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Server Side code for websocket connection:

```
package com.servlet.pushServlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/echo")
public class EchoEndpoint {
   @OnMessage
   public void onMessage(Session session, String msg) {
      try {
         session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Send something");
         System.out.println("Some thing recieved");
         session.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {  }
   }
}
```

Comment: Stop posting the same question every time. This is the 3rd time you did it: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886891/onmessage-onopen-etc-not-fired-in-javascript-client) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885953/websockets-callback-functions-opopen-onmessage-etc-not-firing-in-javascrip). If you don't receive an answer, just wait or edit your question to bring it back on top

Comment: I have not got any replies on any of the question. What exactly am i supposed to do ?

Comment: Wait, add additional comments, browse the internet, try to solve it yourself. The **last** thing you should do is open duplicate issues. That's a good way to really upset the admins =)